# Unable to add swift script as build script in Xcode iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to execute the script `script.swift` as a build phase in Xcode.

`script.swift` is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun --sdk macosx swift

import Foundation
```

I added a build phase with the following shell script:

```
swift "${SRCROOT}/Scripts/script.swift"
```

[image]

The result is the errors in the attached screenshot.
I must import Foundation in my script because I use String, URL, etc.

Is there a way to run such script from Xcode build phase?

Comment: Hey @Erik did you ever work this out?